# Faster method for changing row entries?

Tags: pandas, python-3.5

I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
In [55]: df.head()
Out[55]: 
          Country  Energy Supply  Energy Supply per Capita  % Renewable
0     Afghanistan   3.210000e+08                      10.0    78.669280
1         Albania   1.020000e+08                      35.0   100.000000
2         Algeria1   1.959000e+09                      51.0     0.551010
3  American Samoa            NaN                       NaN     0.641026
4         Andorra   9.000000e+06                     121.0    88.695650
```

and suppose I want to remove every numeric character from each entries in `df['Country']`
I wrote the following code:

```
In [15]: for c in energy['Country']:
   ....:     c = ''.join([i for i in c if not i.isdigit()])
   ....:
```

and when I call `df.head()`, output is same i.e no changes at all. As far as I know this method just assigns new value to variable c but doesn't make changes in dataframe(Am I right?)

so I tried new code:

```
In [51]: k = 0

In [52]: for c in df['Country']:
   ....:     df.loc[k, "Country"] = ''.join([i for i in c if not i.isdigit()])
   ....:     k += 1
   ....:
```

and It worked.
I surely know that this is a very slow method(2nd one),is there any faster method available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize Pandas built-in string operation, str.replace()

```
df['Country'] = df['Country'].str.replace('\d','')
```

Comment: Perhaps you can also point out that the original method did not work because they were just reassigning `c` to a new name and not replacing the original element?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) function. And use Python Module `re` can do this easily.

```
import re
df['Country'] = df['Country'].map(lambda x: re.sub('\d', '', x))
```